# time on clock vs. hour

Tags: c#, time

so i have been searching the net for 2 weeks for making 6 o'clock in the morning as a variable to be the start of the day with

```
TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(06,30,00);
```

But the problem is, it translate the time as an hour thus when i do

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today);
double span = (now - start);
```

I get timenow(3:00pm) - 6 hours and 30 minutes instead of timenow(3:00 PM) - 6:30 AM so what i need is to get the difference between timenow and the start with double so that the answer will show 1.5 hrs instead of 1 hr and 30 mins and also do i have to add AM/PM? if so how can i do that and be able to store it in sql database?

Comment: the difference between timenow and start and to show the minutes

Comment: This sounds very confusing, maybe try to reword/format the second part of your question and include some examples? Do you want "6:30am" to appear as `6.50` or `6.30` for example?

Comment: Are you trying to do this to convert timezones?

Comment: nope i computing for total hours between timenow and start

Answer (score 0):

With this approach, it is clear that this means morning

```
var todayMorning = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6).AddMinutes(30);
var hoursTillNow = (DateTime.Now - todayMorning).TotalHours;
var minutesTillNow = (DateTime.Now - todayMorning).TotalMinutes;

var todayEvening = DateTime.Today.AddHours(18).AddMinutes(30);
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly 6 o'clock in the morning is `new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0)` while `new TimeSpan(6, 30, 0)` is 06:30. It's not clear whether the code or the description is in error here.

> DateTime now = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today);

That isn't valid. `DateTime now = DateTime.Today;` is valid, but it will be for today rather than now, that is to say it will be the same as midnight at the start of today. You perhaps want `DateTime now = DateTime.Now` for local time or `DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow` for UTC.

> (now - start)

This will take a certain amount of time away from a date-time. E.g. right now it is `2017-01-20 10:03:01` here so taking away 6.5 hours gives me `2017-01-20 03:33:24`.

To get the span between two date-times we need two date-times:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime halfSixThisMorning = DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(6, 30, 0);
TimeSpan span = now - halfSixThisMorning;
```

And then `span.TotalHours` is a `double` with the number of hours in `span` including fractional parts.